# particular solution of nonhomogeneous sec order DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

so for non homogeneous part
$ = A sin wx + B sinh wx $

do I pick $y_p = y_{p1} + y_{p2} $ ? one for sin one for sinh ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $y_p$ will be $y_p^{(1)} + y_p^{(2)}$, where $y_p^{(1)}$ is what you'd pick if you just had the sine term, and $y_p^{(2)}$ is what you'd pick if you just had the hyperbolic sine term.

So, $y_p = A\sin(wx) + B\cos(wx) + C\sinh(wx) + D\cosh(wx)$

You can get more practice questions for this type of problem here: http://www.dr-mikes-maths.com/ode-examples.html